# Verification of plotted points of intersection and curve orthogonality

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

A unit circle and tractrix (with differential equations respectively),

$$ \cos \phi =y;\, \sin \phi= y $$
and tangent slope
$$\phi   = \theta +\pi/2   $$

are plotted to verify orthogonality.

Due to inadequate precision there is neither orthogonality nor symmetry of points about  $y$ axis.

```
Clear["`.*"];
pp = ParametricPlot[{{-Sin[t], -Cos[t]}, {Cos[t] + Log[Tan[t/2]], 
     Sin[t]}}, {t, -3, 3}, 
   PlotLabel -> " t are slopes & TRACTRIX/ CIRCLE INTRXNS", 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> .145];
FindRoot[{-Sin[t1] == Cos[t2] + Log[Tan[t2/2]], -Cos[t1] == 
   Sin[t2]}, {{t1, 1}, {t2, 1}}]
th1 = 1.8633725347352827` - Pi/2; th2 = 0.29257620794038613` - Pi/2;
c1 = Graphics[Disk[{Cos[th1], Sin[th1]}, 0.07]]; c2 = 
 Graphics[Disk[{Cos[th2], Sin[th2]}, 0.07]]; Show[{pp, c1, c2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Tractrix & Circle]

Only one point is captured. How to remedy the situation?  Would much appreciate your scrutiny.

Comment: Isn't this what you actually want: `FindRoot[{-Sin[t1] == Cos[t2] + Log[Tan[t2/2]], -Cos[t1] == 
   Sin[t2]}, {{t1, 1}, {t2, 1}}]`? The two parameterized curves don't need to intersect at the same `t`.

Comment: Indeed, and thanks. I edited  my question per your suggestion to consider each curve parameter separately...However we capture one point but not the other.. in spite of a consistent sign convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]

intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp]
```

> {{-0.95733,0.288799},{0.957388,0.288799}}

```
Show[pp, Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections}]
```

[image]

If you change the domain to `{t, -Pi, Pi}` you get all 3 intersections:

```
pp2 = ParametricPlot[{{-Sin[t], -Cos[t]}, {Cos[t] + Log[Tan[t/2]], Sin[t]}}, 
   {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotLabel -> " t are slopes & TRACTRIX/ CIRCLE INTRXNS", 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 4}, All}];

intersections2 = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections @ pp2
```

> {{-0.957398, 0.288753}, {1.22465*10^-16, 1.}, {0.957379, 0.288575}}

```
Show[pp2, Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[Large], Point @ intersections2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSolve[{-Sin[t1] == Cos[t2] + Log[Tan[t2/2]], -Cos[t1] == Sin[t2], 
  0 <= t1 < 2 Pi, 0 <= t2 < 2 Pi}, {t1, t2}, Reals]
(*
  {{t1 -> 1.86337, t2 -> 0.292576},
   {t1 -> 3.14159, t2 -> 1.5708},
   {t1 -> 4.41981, t2 -> 2.84902},
   {t1 -> 3.14159, t2 -> 1.5708}}
*)
```

instead of

```
FindRoot[{-Sin[t1] == Cos[t2] + Log[Tan[t2/2]], -Cos[t1] == Sin[t2]},
  {{t1, 1}, {t2, 1}}]
```

The OP does not use the result of `FindRoot` in the code as such.
Instead, the two numbers that constitute a single solution for `{t1, t2}` are hard-coded, with `Pi/2` subtracted from each component:

th1 = 1.8633725347352827`- Pi/2; th2 = 0.29257620794038613` - Pi/2;

Since only the first of them is the parameter for the circle, it's not surprising that the second, the parameter for the tractrix, when plugged into the circle, gives a point unrelated to the tractrix.

The four solutions from `NSolve` correspond to the three points of intersection, including a double point at the top.

```
int = NSolve[{-Sin[t1] == Cos[t2] + Log[Tan[t2/2]], -Cos[t1] == 
     Sin[t2], 0 <= t1 < 2 Pi, 0 <= t2 < 2 Pi}, {t1, t2}, Reals];
c1 = Graphics[Disk[{Cos[t1 - Pi/2], Sin[t1 - Pi/2]}, 0.1] /. int]; 
Show[{pp, c1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]